# What is the Linux equivalent of bootinfo command?

Tags: linux, aix

**[bootinfo](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/javasdk/v5r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.java.doc.diagnostics.50/diag/problem_determination/aix_cmd_bootinfo_y.html)** for AIX:

> ...shows whether the hardware in use is 32-bit or 64-bit.

What command/utility for Linux would do this job?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several possible answers depending on what exactly you want to know (I don't know which one AIX's `bootinfo` corresponds to).

- You can see whether the CPU is 64-bit, 32-bit, or capable of both by checking the `flags` line in `/proc/cpuinfo`. You have to know the possible flags on your architecture family. For example, on i386/amd64 platforms, the `lm` flag identifies amd64-capable CPUs (CPUs that don't have that flag are i386-only).
- You can see whether the kernel is 32-bit or 64-bit by querying the architecture with `uname -m`. For example, `i[3456]86` is are 32-bit while `x86_64` is 64-bit. Note that on several architectures, a 64-bit kernel can run 32-bit userland programs, so even if the `uname -m` shows a 64-bit kernel, there is no guarantee that 64-bit libraries will be available.
- You can see what is available in userland by querying the [LSB](http://refspecs.freestandards.org/lsb.shtml) support with the [`lsb_release`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/lsb_release) command. More precisely, `lsb-release -s` prints a `:`-separated list of supported LSB features. Each feature has the formm `module-*version*-architecture`. For example, availability of an ix86 C library is indicated by `core-2.0-ia32`, while `core-2.0-amd64` is the analog for amd64. Not every distribution declares all the available LSB modules though, so more may be available than is detectable in this way.
- You can find out the preferred word size for development (assuming a C compiler is available) by compiling a 5-line C program that prints `sizeof(void*)` or `sizeof(size_t)`.

Answer (score 6):

Usually `uname -m` should do the trick, as should `arch`.

The output of both of these commands will tell you the architecture for which the kernel was built.  Whether this is 32 or 64 bit is usually pretty clear (x86_64 and ia64 are two possible 64-bit architectures).  However, note that you could have a 32-bit kernel while running on 64-bit hardware.  If you really want to know about the hardware try looking at either

`less /proc/cpuinfo`

if the "flags" line has 'lm' in it, then it is 64 bit.

Or, if you have `lshw`

`lshw -class processor`

and look at the "width" line.

For both of these options, `grep` can be employed to quickly get the answer without looking at the output.

Comment: More precisely, `uname -m` tells you the architecture for which the *kernel* was built. For example there are a few systems out there with an amd64 kernel but a 32-bit userland.

Comment: Excellent point Gilles.  I updated my answer accordingly.